# NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.auth' when trying to run on Chrome in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web

We are trying to build a WebApp in flutter. Our app runs on a simulator without any errors. I've been able to pull the app up on a Chrome browser without any issues. But when I try to sign in (using email and password with firebase) it's giving me this error in the terminal:

NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.auth'

I've seen a lot of people asking the same thing but none of the answers seem to be fixing the issue.

Here's my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="makeshift_homeschool_app">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>makeshift_homeschool_app</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyB8KqDPKUzCjun4TqVanvnyObjE5fGqc4g",
    authDomain: "makeshift-homeschool-281816.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://makeshift-homeschool-281816.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "makeshift-homeschool-281816",
    storageBucket: "makeshift-homeschool-281816.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "60367595636",
    appId: "1:60367595636:web:84014c2d6a7c4493920921",
    measurementId: "G-VBYH88L0VN"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I've tried putting the firebase-app.js code in the `<head>` but it didn't work for me.

Does anyone know how to fix this?